# Repeated logging in console

Tags: disk-utility, macos

On macOS Sierra I am seeing the following logged every 3 seconds.

```
logd[67]: _handle_cache_delete_with_urgency(0x7f939281eb80, 3, 0)
logd[67]: _volume_contains_cached_data(is /private/var/db/diagnostics/ in /) - YES
logd[67]: 186377856 bytes of purgeable space from log files
logd[67]: _purge_uuidtext only runs at urgency 0 (3)
logd[67]: 0 bytes of purgeable space from uuidtext files
```

I rebooted into Recovery mode (Command-R during boot) and ran Disk Utility First Aid, with no change in behaviour.

With each run of First Aid I received the following in the Disk Utility list of messages:

```
resizing core storage logical volume structures ...
resized core storage logical volume ...
growing file system
```

Which seems odd that each run of First Aid would cause a change to the core storage system.

I'm concerned all of these messages in the log suggests I may have a disk error. Can I safely ignore these? Is my disk failing, or is this normal to have my log files flooded with messages every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out iStat Menus was the culprit. Upgrading to the latest version resolved the issue.

Comment: We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions